# Why should MySQL Connector cursor.execute() params be variables?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am trying to create a filter for my API using MySQL connector for python.
I process user generated queries that look like this:

`user_type_id > 1` and use them in the `WHERE` clause.

Since queries are from users, I want to pass them as params in cursor.execute(query, params) to avoid injection.

When I run

`cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE %s > %s", ('user_type_id', 1))`

it doesn't work as I want it to.

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) states that

> params are bound to the variables in the operation.

Since they don't let params include anything other than variables (column names for example), I suppose there is a reason.

Can you tell me the reason for only allowing variables to be passed as params?
I would also like to know if there are any good workarounds for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want users to be able to generate three things:

- the field (can't be parameterizeda, and it looks like those correspond to column names in your DB)
- the comparator (can't be parameterized)
- the value for the field
  (which can be parameterized)

Fortunately, there's a very limited set of values for the field and the comparator. Can you build a list of those and then validate them yourself before concatenating them to the query?

Something like:

```
def create_query(
    field: str, comparator: str, field_value: int
) -> typing.Tuple[str, typing.Tuple]:
    allowed_fields = ("user_type_id", "user_age")  # for example
    allowed_comparators = (">", "<", "=")
    if field not in allowed_fields:
        raise ValueError(f"{field!r} not in allowed_fields {allowed_fields!r}")
    if comparator not in allowed_comparators:
        raise ValueError(
            f"{comparator!r} not in allowed_comparators {allowed_comparators!r}"
        )

    return f"SELECT * FROM table WHERE {field} {comparator} %s", (field_value,)
```

The above cannot be SQL-injected because you're checking against a strict whitelist before you append to the query and you can enumerate all possible values for those strings. You just have to be *very vigilant* that you can check this for all possible fields.

NOTE: while I think this is the only way to do something like this and it's secure, I haven't worked on a production system that uses this and I'd very much like to know if someone can find a problem with the function above

Comment: Thanks for a great idea! What do you think is the reasoning for not allowing comparators or fields to be parameterized?